# Android Google Maps [React Native?] “API key not found. Check that..” Error

Tags: api, google-maps, react-native

I followed the instructions here https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md to use MapView on my react-native project. I write in the good place my google map API key but the code still not find it. 
Sometimes this error does not appear and my application just crash.

My react-native version is 0.60.4 so I only did the modification for version 0.59 and higher but to verify I also tried with the others modification and nothing resolve this problem.

This is android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="A...w"/>
</application>
```

This is android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
/**
 + Project-wide Gradle configuration properties
 */
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    playServicesVersion = "11.8.0" // or set latest version
    androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
}
```

And this is my App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native'

//import Main from './screens/Main'
import Navigation from './Navigation/Navigation'

import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

export default class App extends React.Component{


  _loadSports(){

  }
  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <MapView
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
/>
      </View>
      //<Navigation/>
      )
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container : {
    flex : 1,
    alignItems : 'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
  }
})
```

I just expect to solve this problem :/

Comment: Do you mean for version 0.60 and higher? just to make sure you didn't link the package

Comment: Yes for 0.60 and higher and I didn't link the package

Comment: Is billing enabled on your project? And the Maps SDK for Android? Which version are you using, 17.0.0? Is your API key properly restricted? Can you post the full error log you're getting, and does it happen regardless of emulator / device?

Answer (score 0):

If your React-Native version is less than (0.6) 
You have to add this to the setting.gradle file

```
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
```

if the error persist please follow the docs carefully on
[github react-native-maps installation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because of application is running. Stop your running application and rerun it.